# Does Java execute code sequentially within a single thread?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, semantics

my code looks like the following:

```
SomeType first = null;
if(true){
   first = new SomeType();
}
first.setSomething();
```

In this case I will receive a `NullPointerException` at the last line at runtime, but **NOT** when debugging. It seems that code execution after the if-statement continues, although the if-statement is not completely processed. Everything works at runtime when I change the code to:

```
SomeType first = new SomeType();
first.setSomething();
```

It doesn't seem that the code execution at runtime aligns with the expected order at compile time. In the case above I always expect "first" to be instantiated before ".setSomething()" is called?

Comment: It can run non-sequentially if it doesn't affect the outcome of the program. In your case, the order cannot change and you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: Not possible, you have something wrong on your environment. Just a wild guess: your compiled class at runtime is old and does have an NPE. When you debug you do it on your current code. Can you explain what environment are you using to compile & debug? Can you provide a simple project that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Could you include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the actuall `Stacktrace` within your question? Otherwise this seems like a [xy Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Question.

Comment: I don't think that is possible can you please specify your environment

Comment: maybe the runtime version was compiled with `if (false) { ...`?

Comment: Is this literally the code you run? Or did you simplify a more complex condition to `true` because you think it is true.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with [tag:syntax].

Comment: This could be the result of a branch prediction going wrong, so the object doesn't get initialized, however unlikely, because I'd hazard a guess that the compiler would optimize the if statement away if it's always true.